Give an example of a function $f(n)$ that does not satisfy the polynomial-growth condition but for which $f(\Theta(n)) = \Theta(f(n))$
Give an example of a function $f(n)$ that does not satisfy the polynomial-growth condition but for which $f(\Theta(n)) = \Theta(f(n))$.
a function $f(n)$ defined on all sufficiently large positive reals satisfies polynomial-growth condition if there exists a constant $\hat{n}>0$ such that the following holds: for every constant $\phi >1$, there exists a constant $d>1$(depending on $\phi$) such that $f(n)/d<f(\psi n)<df(n)$ for all $1\leq\psi\leq\phi$ and $n\geq\hat{n}$
It is a exercise in textbook Introduction to Algorithms Fourth Edition 4.7-4
I try $n^{\lg^{(k)}n}$ and $2^{\lceil \lg n \rceil}$ but fail

Notice that the two conditions are very close. Indeed, $\psi n = \Theta(n)$ and any sequence $g$ which verifies $d^{-1}f(n) \leqslant g(n) \leqslant df(n)$ is $\Theta(f(n))$. So if you look for "well behaved functions" with a simple explicit definition, it will most likely fail.
Since the exercice appears in an algorithmic book, I suggest you try to build $f$ algorithmically instead of looking for explicit examples.
